# Choosing view to load other then default at app launch in Tab bar

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

Is it possible in a Tab Bar Controller to make a tab other than the first be the default view that shows up when app is launched?

To better illustrate, when the app launch, instead of document being the first screen is it possible to set "settings" as the first screen? without reorganizing the placement of the items in the tab bar?

[image]

Comment: You can change the selected index of tabbarcontroller like this self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UITabBarController` has a property called `selectedIndex`. I think that's what you're looking for. In your case, you need to set it to 2 as you want **Settings** page to be displayed first.